# Internal Server Error when export sql table data to Excel sheet (PHP)

Tags: php, pdo, export-to-excel

I need to export my sql data table to Excel sheet. Here I mentioned all of the codes. When I triggered the function called **exportData()**, as a response, I got an Internal Server Error problem (500). I don't have an idea about what I went wrong. Please help me to solve it.

```
public function exportData(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `issue recodes`";
    $exe = $GLOBALS['mydatabase']->query($sql);
    $rows = $exe->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //print_r($rows);
    //define data file name
    $filename = "Backup_on_".date("Ymd")."xls";
    
    //download file
    header("Content-diposition : attachment; filename = '$filename'");
    header("Content-type : application/vnd.ms-excel");
    
    //render xls data
    $heading = false;
    if(!empty($rows)){
        // if the database has data then
        foreach($rows as $value){
            if(!$heading){
                //Already not heading written
                echo implode("\t" ,array_keys($value) . "\n" );
                $heading = true;
            }else{
                // If heading already wrote
                echo implode("\t" , array_values($value) . "\n");
            }
            
            
        }
        return true;
    }else{
        // if the database has not data
    }
}
```

And so on, When I ignoreed **header()** lines, it will get an error like this

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mos\admin\PHP files\admin.php:114 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mos\admin\PHP files\admin.php(114): implode('\t', 'Array\n') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mos\admin\PHP files\export.php(5): PHI\admin\Admin->exportData() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mos\admin\PHP files\admin.php on line 114

Here are the export.php codes that where the above **exportData()** function is called from

```
//export issues as excel data sheet
require_once 'admin.php';
$admin = new PHI\admin\Admin();
if($admin->exportData()){
echo "downloaded";
}else{
echo "fail";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo implode("\t" ,array_keys($value) . "\n" );
```

`array_keys($value) . "\n"` creates a string value (with the array being replaced by the *word* `Array`, because that's what happens when an array gets coerced into a string context), so you are feeding a string to `implode` here as second parameter, instead of an array.

This needs to happen the other way around - implode the array first, append \n after:

```
echo implode("\t" ,array_keys($value)) . "\n";
```

And the same for that other line in the else branch.

But you should really be using [`fputcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to begin with, rather than this construct. Yours will create a faulty CSV, if any of the data fields ever contains the separator character \t. `fputcsv` has the necessary "escaping" mechanism for that already implemented.